# Handling deletion of documents with relational fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have 3 collections, Users, Posts and Comments.

User Schema

```
{
  posts: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post' }],
  likes: {
    comments: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }],
    posts: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post' }],
  }
}
```

Post Schema

```
{
  author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  likes: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
  comments: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }],
}
```

Comment Schema

```
{
  author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  post: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post', },
}
```

Right now this is the steps i make to delete a Post and everything that relate to it such as deleting the post id from the author document posts field, user likes on post, comments, user likes on comments.

This is the function i use and it works and everything is great but i wonder if there is a better way of handling this problem ?

```
PostSchema.statics.deletePost = async function (postId) {
  const post = await this.findById(postId);
  const commentIds = post.comments;

  await Promise.all([
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(
      post.author,
      { $pull: { posts: postId } },
    ),
    User.updateMany(
      { _id: { $in: post.likes } },
      { $pull: { 'likes.posts': postId } },
    ),
    commentIds.map(async (commentId) => {
      const comment = await Comment.findById(commentId);

      User.findByIdAndUpdate(
        comment.author._id,
        { $pull: { comments: commentId } },
      );

      User.updateMany(
        { _id: { $in: comment.likes } },
        { $pull: { 'likes.comments': commentId } },
      );
    }),
    this.findByIdAndDelete(postId),
  ]);

  return post._id;
};
```

Comment: For the clean code you must use `await` with every single promise. And with the array of promise you should use `Promise.all`. Otherwise your code is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can create inconsistency in database.

when dealing with multiple documents, then use MULTI-DOCUMENT TRANSACTIONS new feature in MongoDB 4. Which means either all the documents/collection will be updated or none if something went wrong. Transaction as a whole will be atomic.

OR

Design schema efficiently which includes all of your 3 different schemas. Because an operation on a single document is atomic.
read here
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/